# Exporting rgl.snapshot and rgl.postscript fails

Tags: r, plot, export, rgl

I am currently using the `rgl` package for some data representation. 
Here's my command

```
mypath("directory")
png(file=mypath, res=600, width=10.5, height= 10.5,units="in",bg = "transparent")
require(rgl)
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(replicate(4,sample(1:200,1000,rep=TRUE)))
colnames(df) <- c("var1","var2","var3","var4")
plot3d(x=df$var1, y=df$var2, z=df$var3, col=as.numeric(df$var4), size=0.5, type='s',xlab="var1",ylab="var2",zlab="var3")
rgl.snapshot(mypath)
```

The command above works and produces a tiny image, which I wasn't able to make bigger, or increase its resolution (to 600).

I have also tried to export a pdf using:

```
rgl.postscript(mypath, fmt="pdf")
```

but when I execute the command R goes into a "not responding" state.

Can somebody please show me how to properly export the file? I would prefer the have the PNG with the resolution 600 dpi.

Cheers,

Comment: I think the size of the snapshot might be tied to the size of the graphics window in which you are producing the RGL plot?

Comment: Hi @BenBolker, I have tried to set the window size and resolution (see the edit), yet I got an empty white file. Surprisingly, the file was 37.5 Kbs, and not zero.

Answer (score 1):

A solution can be to set the size of the window using open3d() :

```
require(rgl)
set.seed(1)

df <- data.frame(replicate(4,sample(1:200,1000,rep=TRUE)))
colnames(df) <- c("var1","var2","var3","var4")
open3d(windowRect=c(100,100,700,700))
plot3d(x=df$var1, y=df$var2, z=df$var3, col=as.numeric(df$var4), size=0.5, type='s',xlab="var1",ylab="var2",zlab="var3")
rgl.snapshot(<path to png file>)
```

Comment: This does not work on Ubuntu 14.04, I got only a small capture of the upper left corner and I guess this is what @Error404 was experiencing.

Answer (score 0):

May be someone need. I used the following combination for persp3Drgl:

```
persp3Drgl(...)
par3d( windowRect=c( 0,0,100,100 ) )
snapshot3d( file.path(plotDir, "3D.png"), top = TRUE )
```

Without `top = TRUE` it got failed.